# DirectShow filter missing in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I am trying to stream system audio from Windows 10 via FFMPeg but my built-in audio output device (Realtek) does not show up when I run `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

[image: ffmpeg direct show audio devices]

But the realtek audio device works and it also shows up as registered in Graph Studio Next, a direct show device browser:

[image: RealTek Audio DirectShow Filters]

OS: Windows 10, 64 bit
FFMPEG: 4.3.2 (latest)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the loopback device. It usually starts with 'Stereo Mix'.

Go to Control Panel --> Sound --> Recording. Right-click and make sure all devices are shown. Enable the 'Stereo Mix'.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my week.